# pickerview of the iPhone

Tags: iphone

how to crate a picker view in the iPhone 
which was perfomed of the picker view of the unitconverter

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a pickerview see this
[UIPickerView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html)

And there is no unit converter pickerview. You have to implement pickerview data source and delegate methods to get a unit converter working on pickerview.